# Installing helm chart using Terraform helm provider

Tags: azure, kubernetes, terraform, azure-aks, terraform-provider-helm

I was trying to deploy a helm chart using Terraform helm provider. With the below code I'm able to create a helm release and created namespace for the resources.

```
provider "helm" {

  kubernetes {

   kube_config_path = trim(base64decode(data.test.config.result.config_path), "\n")
exec {
api_version = "client.authentication.k8s.io/v1"
command     = "kubelogin"
args = [
  "get-token",
  "--login", "spn",
  "--environment", "AzurePublicCloud",
  "--server-id", "6dae42f8-4368-4678-94ff-3960e28e3630",
  "--tenant-id", data.azurerm_client_config.current.tenant_id,
  "--client-id", data.azurerm_client_config.current.client_id,
  "--client-secret",  data.azurerm_key_vault_secret.service_principal_key.value,
 ]
}

 }
   debug       = true
}


resource "helm_release" "helmrelname" {
 name = "helmrelname"

 repository       = "https://mycompany.github.io/charts"
 chart            = "helmrelname1"
 namespace        = "helmrelname-test"
create_namespace = true
timeout          = 800
wait_for_jobs    = true
wait             = true
force_update     = true
set {
name  = "helmrelname.monitoring.create"
value = "false"
type  = "auto"
}
depends_on = [data.test.config]

lifecycle {
ignore_changes = all
}
}
```

On "terraform apply" I could see that the execution failed with below error

```
query: failed to query with labels: secrets is forbidden: User "3df53t-3fea-48b4-a932-3061e1fec6cc" cannot list resource "secrets" in API group "" in the namespace "helmrelname-test"
```

What I should do to resolve this?

Note:
"3df53t-3fea-48b4-a932-3061e1fec6cc" is the service principal object id

Comment: the sp doesnt have permissions inside aks. You need to create a role assignment for it.

Comment: Did you mean role assignment or role binding?. If role assignment then I have created it already

Comment: I mean role binding inside kubernetes. Unless you add the service principal to one of the aad groups that get automatic role binding for cluster admin. You can go to cluster configuration on aks in azure portal and check if any groups are automatically mapped to cluster admin.

Answer (score 0):

Seems issue was casued because of service principal permissions.
Replicated the same via below code.

**Step1:**
created a service principal by running below command

```
az ad sp create-for-rbac -n "demo-helm"
```

**Output as follow**
[image]

**Step2:**
main tf file as follows
NOTE: Copy the above secret password and appid information

```
data "azurerm_resource_group" "example" {
  name     = "*********"
}
data "azuread_client_config" "current" {}

provider "helm" {

  kubernetes {

  // kube_config_path = trim(base64decode(data.test.config.result.config_path), "\n")
exec {
api_version = "client.authentication.k8s.io/v1"
command     = "kubelogin"
args = [
  "get-token",
  "--login", "spn",
  "--environment", "AzurePublicCloud",
  "--server-id", "*****************************",
  "--tenant-id", "*****************************",
  "--client-id", "*****************************",
  "--client-secret",  "*****************************",

 ]
}

 }
   debug       = true
}


resource "helm_release" "helmrelname" {
 name = "helmrelname"

 repository       = "https://mycompany.github.io/charts"
 chart            = "helmrelname1"
 namespace        = "helmrelname-test"
create_namespace = true
timeout          = 800
wait_for_jobs    = true
wait             = true
force_update     = true
set {
name  = "helmrelname.monitoring.create"
value = "false"
type  = "auto"
}
//depends_on = [data.test.config]

lifecycle {
ignore_changes = all
}
}
```

Step3:
Upon running plan and apply

```
terraform plan
terraform apply -auto-approve
```

[image]

NOTE: We need valid chart repository access configured on portal.

Answer (score 0):

Added the clusterrolebinding for cluster admin role to  objecid "3df53t-3fea-48b4-a932-3061e1fec6cc" and issue got resolved.

Command used.

```
 kubectl create clusterrolebinding --clusterrole cluster-admin --user "3df53t-3fea-48b4-a932-3061e1fec6cc"
```

Comment: Just some random user? Or what user is that guid for?

Comment: secret was forbidden for the user ""3df53t-3fea-48b4-a932-3061e1fec6cc". So you need to add the cluster-admin role to it. But make sure that you provide this role only for some trusted user because it is having access to entire cluster